# Three.js - Shape fill color

Tags: javascript, three.js, shapes, fill

I have the following code which draws a yellow circle:

```
  var radius = 5,
    segments = 64,
    material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xF0C400 } ),
    geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( radius, segments );

  geometry.vertices.shift();
  var circle = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);

  circle.position.set(5,5,0);
  circle.rotation.set(1.57,0,0);
  scene.add(circle);
```

My only question is how do I get this circle filled with color? I tried to change the material but I still only see the outline shape..

**Update:** I had to change the THREE.Line to THREE.Mesh..!

Comment: for me this draws an eclipse..?why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xF0C400, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );

geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( radius, segments );

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

For a more general solution, see http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_shapes.html

three.js r.66

Comment: Thank you so much. I wish there was a complete documentation for Three.js, instead of a bunch of random examples..

Comment: @lephleg a bit late but here you go: - [circlebuffergeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/CircleBufferGeometry)

Comment: @circlebuffergeometry thanks mate! I don't even remember what was this all about! :D